# Comparing Two 1 column 2d Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2d array

```
  0 1  0  
  0 *  0  
  0 *  0    
  0 2  0  
  0 *  0
```

That I altered to be this

```
0 * 0      
0 * 0     
0 * 0    
0 1 0    
0 2 0
```

By doing this

```
    Dot[][] tempDot = dotArray;
  ArrayList<Descriptor> movedList = new ArrayList<Descriptor>();
  for(int j=0; j<this.getHeight(); j++){
for (int i=this.getHeight()-1; i>0; i--){
    if(dotArray[i][col] == null){
        dotArray[i][col] = dotArray[i-1][col];
        dotArray[i-1][col] = null;
    }
}
        }
```

Now I'm trying to figure out how compare the second column in the first one to the second column in the second one. I have to return a "Descriptor" object which contains the original location any non-null that moved down. I have tried doing nesting for loops to check the first value in each loop and then finding the first value in the second loop but that wasn't working. Any help would be great!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add a tag describing which language or environment this is in.

Answer (score 0):

If `Descriptor` is defined like this,

```
private class Descriptor {
    Descriptor(int from, int to, Dot[] dots) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.dots = dots;
    }

    public int from;
    public int to;
    public Dot[] dots;
}
```

you can do this way.

```
    // Store original location(index) of each row.
    Map<Dot[], Integer> originLocMap = new HashMap<Dot[], Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < tempDot.length; i++) {
        originLocMap.put(tempDot[i], i);
    }

    // Sort rows by second column (dot[*][1])
    for (int i = tempDot.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (tempDot[i][1] != null) {
            continue;
        }

        for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {  
            if (tempDot[j][1] != null) {
                Dot[] temp = tempDot[i];
                tempDot[i] = tempDot[j];
                tempDot[j] = temp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Collect location change data
    ArrayList<Descriptor> movedList = new ArrayList<Descriptor>();
    for (int i = tempDot.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (tempDot[i][1] == null) {
            break;
        }

        Dot[] dots = tempDot[i];
        int from = originLocMap.get(dots);
        Descriptor descriptor = new Descriptor(from, i, dots);
        movedList.add(descriptor);
    }


    Iterator<Descriptor> it = movedList.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Descriptor d = it.next();
        System.out.println(d.from + " ==> " + d.to);
    }
```